# Database structure for metaquery

Tags: database, couchdb, cloudant

I have a database that has a the following structure:

```
+------+------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| item | type | color  | speed | length | width |
+------+------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|    1 |    1 |      3 |     1 |      2 |     2 |
|    2 |    1 |      5 |     3 |      1 |     1 |
|    3 |    1 |      6 |     3 |      1 |     1 |
|    4 |    2 |      2 |     1 |      3 |     1 |
|    5 |    2 |      2 |     2 |      2 |     1 |
|    6 |    2 |      4 |     2 |      3 |     1 |
|    7 |    2 |      5 |     1 |      1 |     2 |
|    8 |    3 |      1 |     2 |      2 |     2 |
|    9 |    4 |      4 |     3 |      1 |     2 |
|   10 |    4 |      6 |     3 |      3 |     2 |
+------+------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

I would like to efficiently query what combination of fields are valid. So, for example, I'd like to query the database for the following:

What values of color are valid if type is 1?

```
ans: [3, 5, 6]
```

What values of speed are valid if type is 2 and color is 2?

```
ans: [1, 2]
```

What values of type are valid if length is 2 and width is 2?

```
ans: [1, 2]
```

The SQL equivalents are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `color` FROM `cars` WHERE `type` =2
SELECT DISTINCT `speed` FROM `cars` WHERE `type` =2 AND `width` =2
SELECT DISTINCT `type` FROM `cars` WHERE `length` =2 AND `width` =2
```

I'm planning on using a cloud based database (Cloudant DBAAS - based on CouchDB). How would this best be implemented, keeping in mind that there may be thousands of items with tens of fields?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirements correctly. Is what you're trying to do in the first example equivalent to an SQL query like "Select color where type = 1"? That would be very easy to translate to CouchDB views.

Comment: Updated the Question with equivalent SQL queries.

Comment: @Terry did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't put too much thought into this question, so there may be errors in the approach, but one option is to represent each row with a document:

```
{
  "_id": "1db91338150bfcfe5fcadbd98fe77d56",
  "_rev": "1-83daafc1596c2dabd4698742c2d8b0cf",
  "item": 1,
  "type": 1,
  "color": 3,
  "speed": 1,
  "length": 2,
  "width": 2
}
```

Note the `_id` and `_rev` fields have been automatically generated by Cloudant for this example.

You could then create a secondary index on the `type` field:

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.type)
        emit(doc.type);
}
```

To search using the `type` field:

https://accountname.cloudant.com/dashboard.html#database/so/_design/ddoc/_view/col_for_type?key=1&include_docs=true

A secondary index on the `type` and `width` fields:

```
function(doc) {
  if( doc.type && doc.width)
    emit([doc.type, doc.width]);
}
```

To search using the `type` and `width` fields:

https://accountname.cloudant.com/dashboard.html#database/so/_design/ddoc/_view/speed_for_type_and_width?key=[1,2]&include_docs=true

A secondary index on the `length` and `width` fields:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.length && doc.width)
        emit([doc.length, doc.width]);
}
```

To search using the `length` and `width` fields:

https://accountname.cloudant.com/dashboard.html#/database/so/_design/ddoc/_view/type_for_length_and_width?key=[2,2]&include_docs=true

The complete design document is here:

```
{
  "_id": "_design\/ddoc",
  "_rev": "3-c87d7c3cd44dcef35a030e23c1c91711",
  "views": {
    "col_for_type": {
      "map": "function(doc) {\n    if(doc.type)\n        emit(doc.type);\n}"
    },
    "speed_for_type_and_width": {
      "map": "function(doc) {\n  if( doc.type && doc.width)\n    emit([doc.type, doc.width]);\n}"
    },
    "type_for_length_and_width": {
      "map": "function(doc) {\n    if (doc.length && doc.width)\n        emit([doc.length, doc.width]);\n}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```